# PVLIB setting DC power ratio

Tags: python, pvlib, solar

I've been requested to use pvlib with python to estimate solar PV performance, and from the documentation most of it seems logical. However, the examples show that you specify a module, and an inverter, and there doesn't appear to be any variable that sets the ratio between the two?

This number must exist, as running the model gives an annual output, but modern solar parks have a 1.4:1 DC:AC ratio. I am hoping I'm missing something obvious, and someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could that be implicit?

Comment: You're right my question was unclear, I've been looking for either the ratio or where I can set the DC amount, in the examples though there seems to be no DC size set at all?

Comment: which models are you trying to use? pvwatts? sapm? single diode?

Comment: Hi Will,  I was trying to use the sapm method, and I've found after digging around in the docs that you can set number of panels in a string and number of strings on the inverter, which then allows me to set the DC MWp for my inverter. I then just need to multiply the results by the number of inverters in the park, I think. edit - to be clear those two parameters are in the PVSystem class, modules_per_string and strings_per_inverter

Comment: yes, that is a recommend approach for that model. pull request welcome if you have ideas on making documentation more clear.